# Run jar with spring profile environment variable

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I'm trying to use a spring profile argument to run a jar file, the profile isn't working:

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active="test" build/libs/moley2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Here is my application.yml file:

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
server:
  port:8000
---
spring:
  profiles: test
server:
  port:9000
```

The jar was created using `gradle build` in the projects root directory. Running the jar with the command provided starts on port 8080 so it seems like the profile isn't loading. I'm sure I'm missing something simple here as I'm new to gradle / spring. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure that `gradle build` create a jar file?

Comment: yeah I mean that command runs fine, I don't think it would without a valid jar file. Just doesn't load the profile bc the port stays on 8080

Comment: Remove the `"` those shouldn't be including and better to use a regular argument `java -jar build/libs/moley2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.profiles.active=test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property server should be:

```yaml
server:
  port: 9000
```

Instead of:

```yaml
server:
  port:9000
```

A space is missing between the colon and the value.

---

Also notice that configuring the profile as:

```yaml
spring:
  profiles: dev
```

is [deprecated since 2.4.0](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4#profile-specific-documents) version and should be replaced with:

```yaml
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev
```

More info in the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-file-activation-properties). Or a tutorial [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml).

Comment: Thanks I changed the space, did a gradle clean and gradle build, and now it defaults to the test profile port even when it properly loads the dev profile. I get: The following profiles are active: dev but now tomcat starts on 9000 even though 8000 is specified for dev

Comment: It worked after switching to the non-deprecated yaml. Thank you @Marc